# Drupal Theming a block

Tags: php, drupal

I just created a block that was added to the Footer region of my theme.
However, I need to theme it and I'm not having much luck.

The footer currently has two blocks, contribute_button and the powered_by block.
I currently have block--footer.tpl.php overriding how the footer region is rendered, is that causing my problem?

How can I theme the contribute_button block in my footer region? block--contribute_button.tpl.php isn't effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Theme developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) is Your friend, You could check the suggestions. And don't forget to clear template registry cache.

Answer (score 0):

I think page-footer.tpl.php will work. Just try it once.

Answer (score -1):

Pls provide your sites link here  and I can have a look and advice you.

Also Try in css to use #contribute_button block but this is my guess.

Cheers,
vishal